# Binary search tree, how to connect nodes to root?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int element;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    int height=-1;
};


struct BST
{
    bool isSameRoot=true;
    int hight=0;
    node* root=NULL ;
    void addElement(int n);
    void insert(node* Node,int number);
    void preorder(node* p);

};

void BST::addElement(int n)
{
    insert(root, n);
    cout << "Adding" << endl;
}


void BST::insert(node* p,int n)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        p = new node;
        p->element = n;
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;

        if (isSameRoot)// To skip one of the iterations;
        {
            hight++;
        }
        isSameRoot = !isSameRoot;
        p->height = hight;
        cout << "Element is Added:: " << n<<endl;
        cout << "HEIGHT==: " <<p->height<<endl ;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n<p->element)
        {
            insert(p->left, n);
        }
        else if (n>p->element)
        {
            insert(p->right, n);
        }
    }
}

void preorder(node* p)
{
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->element << endl;
        preorder(p->left);
        preorder(p->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    BST* tree=new BST ;

    tree->addElement(8);
    tree->addElement(9);
    tree->addElement(45);
    tree->addElement(25);
    tree->addElement(97);
    tree->addElement(78);

    preorder(tree->root);//Here is the disease;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is probably very basic yet important;

Obviously in a BST we should connect every node to the  root node;

Can you take a look at my code and tell me how to fix this;

Until `preorder()` method, everything works / looks fine;

I thing I didnt use only single root node;

This is my question;
How am I supposed to connect nodes to the root;

Comment: Rather than having every node connecting to root, you should have every node connected to their parent. node *left, *right, *parent

Comment: Please clean your example up a bit. Tab characters still need to be preceded by 4 spaces for this to be more legible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is just to incrementally generate a BST and later dump its contents with a traversal, you don't even need to connect nodes to their parents OR the root, nor do you appear to need to track the height or 'hight' [sic] of the nodes.

**Your problem is that you are not actually building your tree at all.** On your insertion into a NULL node, you only set a temporary pointer to a new node. C++ passes parameters by value, not reference, so the 'p' you think you are setting in the BST is only a temporary copy of the BST's root, and it gets lost (and leaks) at the end of the BST::insert call.

That said, here is some other advice:

- You can pass a (recursively incremented) height index in your insert(...) call rather than storing it in nodes.
- Do the NULL check/node creation for insert in BST::addElement(int n) instead of the BST::insert(...) call, since the null case should only happen on the first insert to the tree, which can only happen on the initial addElement anyway.
- The isSameRoot variable seems like an unneeded hack.

**Edit: I felt bored. Here's your homework answer, please upvote and accept my answer, I could use some more reputation for bounties for my own questions...**

```
struct node {
  int   element;
  node *left;
  node *right;
  node(int n = 0) : element(n), left(NULL), right(NULL) { }
};

struct BST{
  node *root = NULL;    
  void addElement(int n);
  void insert(node &Node, int number);
  void preorder(node *p);
};

void BST::addElement(int n) {
  if (!root) { root = new node(n); }
  else       { insert(*root, n); }
}

void BST::insert(node &p, int n) {
  if (n < p.element) {
    if (!p.left)  { p.left = new node(n); }
    else          { insert(*(p.left), n); }
  }
  else if (n > p.element) {
    if (!p.right) { p.right = new node(n); }
    else          { insert(*(p.right), n); }
  }
}

void preorder(node *p) {
  if (!p) { return; }

  cout << p->element << endl;
  preorder(p->left);
  preorder(p->right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing while(p != NULL) - stuck in infinite loop. if(p != null).